# Executing code from memory

Tags: c, memory, jit

Let say I would like to make sort of JIT compilation in C. I disassemble function and insert it's code in memory right in my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


void* alloc_executable_memory(size_t size) {

  void *ptr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);

  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "mmap failed");
      return NULL;
  }

  return ptr;
}

void push_code_into_memory(unsigned char *memory) {
  unsigned char code[] = {
    0x48, 0x89, 0xf8,       // mov %rdi, %rax
    0,48, 0x83, 0xc0, 0x04, // add $4, %rax
    0xc3                    // ret
  };

  memcpy(memory, code, sizeof(code));
}

int make_memory_executable(void* memory, size_t size) {

  if (mprotect(memory, size, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "mprotect failed");
      return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

const size_t SIZE = 512;
typedef long (*jitFunc)(long);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  void *mem = alloc_executable_memory(SIZE);
  push_code_into_memory((unsigned char *)mem);
  make_memory_executable(mem, SIZE);

  jitFunc foo = (jitFunc)mem;
  int res = foo(2);
  printf("%d\n", res);

  return 0;
}
```

However, I always get segfault 11(macOS) after calling foo. What is wrong with this code? Firstly, I thought that problem was in access rights, but flags seem to be set correctly.

Comment: the debugger could be helpful here.

Comment: Also, you have to make sure that the compiler respects the calling convention required by the jitted function, i.e. the argument `2` must be in `rdi`, not on the stack.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Yes... I'd also make calling conventions explicit, check if you're really running on x64 (and not on x86), and then the real horrors of building your own JIT really get started... I built a couple of JIT's in the past, but nowadays would simply recommend using LLVM.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre debugger threw exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS while calling foo. I have already found problem - it is wrong assemble listing.

Comment: @NikitaRock: that certainly was problematic, but in order to ensure that the code doesn't break under other ABIs/compilers, you have to qualify the `jitFunc` type with a special attribute which specifies the calling convention.

Comment: You can avoid the extra mprotect() system call by passing PROT_EXEC flag too in mmap.

  
    `void *ptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 6):

Think I found it:

```
0,48, 0x83, 0xc0, 0x04
```

should be

```
0x48, 0x83, 0xc0, 0x04
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, such a silly mistake and a lot of wasted time..Now it works correctly